# Multiple images and One xml, or one image and multiple xml?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, layout

Im developing and android App with eclipse,
The question is simple. my app is Always in Landscape mode.

For supporting multiple screen is it better to have different images with different sizes on drawable folders and just have one xml layout file, 
OR it is better to have one image and make diffrent xml files in layout folders?

Comment: You could end up with *not only* different images. But also with different xmls (i.e.: for portrait and landscape).

Comment: there is Just One orientation for my app

Comment: Then, 1 xml. And a lot of images (at least, 1 per density - as usual).

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to go with different images inside the different drawable folders for the resolutions you want to support. Thats what I do generally with my apps.
And is advisable because if the images stretch then they would look ugly on device. So its always better to have different sets of images.

Also depending on the complexity of you layout file, you might end up specifying various dimes.xml like shown below to account for the different padding and dimension needs of you app and how tailored you want it to be for that resolution you desire to support. There is no one magical solution for all resolution in android.

```
drawable
----icon.png
drawable-sw600dp-land
----icon.png
drawable-sw720dp-land
----icon.png
-layout-land
----activity_main.xml
values
----dimens.xml
values-sw600dp-land
----dimens.xml
values-sw720dp-land
----dimens.xml
```